Trying to pass a functionality to a composable
I have a biometric prompt implementation as below:
class BiometricAuthentication(
    private val activity: AppCompatActivity
) {
   
 private val resultChannel = Channel<BiometricResult>()
    val promptResults = resultChannel.receiveAsFlow()

    fun showBiometricPrompt(
        title: String,
        description: String
    ) {
        val manager = BiometricManager.from(activity)
        val authenticators = if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
            BIOMETRIC_STRONG or DEVICE_CREDENTIAL
        } else BIOMETRIC_STRONG

        val promptInfo = PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle(title)
            .setDescription(description)
            .setAllowedAuthenticators(authenticators)

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 30) {
            promptInfo.setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
        }

        when(manager.canAuthenticate(authenticators)) {
            BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                resultChannel.trySend(BiometricResult.HardwareUnavailable)
                return
            }
            BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE -> {
                resultChannel.trySend(BiometricResult.FeatureUnavailable)
                return
            }
            BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED -> {
                resultChannel.trySend(BiometricResult.AuthenticationNotSet)
                return
            }
            else -> Unit
        }

        val prompt = BiometricPrompt(
            activity,
            object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
                    super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
                    resultChannel.trySend(BiometricResult.AuthenticationError(errString.toString()))
                }

                override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                    super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
                    resultChannel.trySend(BiometricResult.AuthenticationSuccess)
                }

                override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
                    super.onAuthenticationFailed()
                    resultChannel.trySend(BiometricResult.AuthenticationFailed)
                }
            }
        )
        prompt.authenticate(promptInfo.build())
    }

    sealed interface BiometricResult {
        data object HardwareUnavailable: BiometricResult
        data object FeatureUnavailable: BiometricResult
        data class AuthenticationError(val error: String): BiometricResult
        data object AuthenticationFailed: BiometricResult
        data object AuthenticationSuccess: BiometricResult
        data object AuthenticationNotSet: BiometricResult
    }
}

To call this, I implement in MainActivity as Follows
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val promptManager by lazy {
        BiometricAuthentication(this)
    }


    private lateinit var navController: NavHostController
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            navController = rememberNavController()
            SetupNavGraph(navController = navController, promptManager = promptManager)
        }
    }
}


And in the SetupNavGraph:

@Composable
fun SetupNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController,
    promptManager: BiometricAuthentication
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screens.Onboarding.route
    ) {
        composable(route = Screens.SomePageThatDoesntneedsBiometericStuffOne.route) {
            OnBoarding(navController = navController, viewModel = viewModel())
        }
        composable(route = Screens.SomePageThatDoesntneedsBiometericStuffTwo.route){
            RegisterUserPageOne(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(route = Screens.SomePageThatneedsBiometericStuffOne.route){
            RegisterUserPageTwo(navController = navController, biometricPromptManager = promptManager)
        }
   }
}


How can I improve this?
